# Is raising an unrelated exception for convenience acceptable?

Tags: python, refactoring, coding-standards, exceptions

Let's say I have a function that returns a dataset. First it tries to read it and if that fails it is requested from an API and then written:

```
def get_dataset():
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(api.get_dataset())
        df.to_csv('dataset.csv')
    return df
```

Now we may want to force making the request and update the CSV file, so we pass a flag. In order to be more concise with the code, we can use a cheap trick to force the execution of the except block:

```
def get_dataset(force_udpate=False):
    try:
        if force_update:
            raise FileNotFoundError
        df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(api.get_dataset())
        df.to_csv('dataset.csv')
    return df
```

Of course this looks bad, because a `FileNotFoundError` is not really applicable. But if we didn't do this we would either have to break the DRY principle:

```
def get_dataset(force_update=False):
    if force_update:
        df = pd.DataFrame(api.get_dataset())
        df.to_csv('dataset.csv')
        return df
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(api.get_dataset())
        df.to_csv('dataset.csv')
    return df
```

Or introduce a local function, dirtying the whole function a bit:

```
def get_dataset(force_update=False):
    def request_and_write():
        d = pd.DataFrame(api.get_dataset())
        d.to_csv('dataset.csv')
        return d

    if force_udpate:
        return request_and_write()
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = request_and_write()
    return df
```

Is that questionable practice acceptable for the sake of code simplicity and clarity?

Comment: You are not violating dry as long as you are catering to different scenarios. Exceptions are thrown to signal exceptional conditions that require special attention. So they 'd better be clear and not deceptive or puzzling. Your laziness will be another man's waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use exceptions to control program flow or *"for convenience"*. It couples the code in a way it shouldn't be.

Exceptions are meant to indicate exceptional cases and error situations which cannot be handled at the place where they are thrown.

---

For your particular case you might prefer to test the file for existence in first place, instead of relying on the exception.
It is not really an *exceptional case* for your code that the files might not exist at that point, and should be handled with some clear code.

Comment: Fair enough... But for simple scenarios like this? Also Python is pretty special with exceptions, they are much more conventionally and flexibly used unlike in other languages.

Comment: @dabadaba I said **never** and literally meant so.